# Quick way to Print Multiple Emails

Tags: mail.app, email, printing

Using Mail.app, or exporting from same, is there a quick way to print all the emails from a single folder?

I have about 50 email messages in a folder and I need to print a copy of each one.  I know I could

- Open each email
- Print it
- Remove it from the tray (to conform it printing)
- Repeat 50 times

That, however, seems super time consuming. I'd rather be able to

- Somehow combine all the emails into a single document
- Print that
- Walk away

I know I can export to mbox, but I don't know of anyway to view a unified mbox as a single logical document (dealing with a combination of plain text, HTML formated, multi-part, attachments, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your request:

I selected 50 emails, then choose Print under File Tab.

It took some time to generate the print files, but then it showed me print preview for 50 emails.

[image: print]

Without proceeding (do not want to waist my toner), I see there is no problem in printing 50 emails all at once.

Comment: That's pretty funny — I guess modern iOS/Web stuff has me trained to think something like that wouldn't work.  Thanks!